# SOAP HttpRequest and the Nagle Algorithm

Tags: .net, soap

SOAP requests are not interactive. Furthermore, they usually cannot be processed by a server until the entire request is received.

Therefore, should we always disable the Nagle algorithm on an HttpWebRequest used for SOAP?

```
HttpWebRequest req = ...;
req.ServicePoint.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
```